# SHA-256 custom length digest

Tags: java, sql-server, security, sha, sha256

I need to allow old users of a website to have access to the new website with the same credentials. The database server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and i dont have permissions to make changes to the database. The password column of the database is set to varchar(50) and a digest is 48 characters. The only information that i have for the passwords is that they have been hashed with sha-256 algoritm but as far as i know a sha-256 digest is 64 characters and not 48. Is it possible to produce the same 48 length digests with sha256?

Comment: An SHA256 digest is 32 bytes, or 64 bytes when represented as a hexadecimal string.  48 bytes may be a Base64 encoded SHA256 hash. Does the digest in the table contain A-Z as opposed to A-F?

Comment: @AlexK I am not sure if i understood your question right.. but the digest in the table i think it is in hex format eg. c8fd968750b3303ad1bfa2ed5ad2dfe0d7a5661eef591e3a

Answer (score 2):

The only two primitive hash functions with native output size of 192 bits (48hex * 1byte/2hex * 8bit/byte) are HAVAL-192 and TIGER-192. None of the others match up exactly.

If they have indeed been hashed with sha256, then they may be truncated (as a hex encoded sha-256 digest is 64 characters.

To deduce the exact situation will take some work. Here are the different ways you can approach it.

- If I had access to the original source code, I'd look at that. Considering you asked the question, I'll assume that's not possible.
- If I could write a record into the old system, I'd set a sentinel password (or find an account I knew the password to). Something that I know. Then I'd find the hashed result from the DB.

  So now we know `p=password` and `h=4d9e...`.

  From there, start by just hashing the password with sha256 and see what you come up with. If you're lucky, you'll find a pattern quickly (like the last half of the hash is just cut off). If you're not lucky, it'll take some digging and trial and error.

  So, for example:

  ```
  p = "password"
  h = "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd6"
  ```

  The result would be: `sha256(p)[0:48]` as `sha256(p) == "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8"`

  ```
  h = "51d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8"
  ```

  The result would be: `sha256(p)[16:48]`

  And so on.
- If I didn't have access to a known password, there would be no way of testing the hypothesis. So if you don't have the source code, and don't know an account in the system, you're basically out of luck. So make those first 2 your top priority.

Beware that you may have to get creative. It's entirely possible that something weird has been done. Such as:

```
salt = h[0:8]
tmp = sha256(p + salt)
h = salt + (tmp[0:16] xor tmp[16:16])
```

So have fun :-)